# Stop proxy server transforming HTTP POST to HTTP GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-headers, node-http-proxy

I have a web app, which has a dashboard functionality.   The app is used by many different companies in many different environments, all browsers.

There is a piece of javascript that refreshes that dashboard every 60 seconds via an http POST to a url which returns JSON.

For one user (and one user only according to my logs) the following .NET error message is generated every 60 seconds from that URL:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: This request has been blocked because sensitive information     could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET    requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

For all other users, there's never a problem.

I know for a fact that this user is on a network which is proxied (Government).  This user is a new user - i.e. we've never had other users on this network.

The above leads me to believe that their proxy is modifying the request for some reason (attempted bandwidth optimisation?), converting the POST to a GET, silently.  My Asp.NET MVC app is (correctly) refusing to honour the request for security reasons.

I'm unlikely to be able to change their proxy setup of course.

I tried adding the following to the action:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore=true)]
```

As well as:

```
Response.Cache.SetNoTransforms();
```

But the problem remains.

Are there any other HTTP headers that I can set to instruct the proxy to stop mangling things?  Any other way of making these proxies behave?  Or is there anything in a browser that might be doing this?

Update: since writing this, another 2 different users, from the same company, are now generating these errors, adding weight to my proxy theory.

Comment: it would seem odd for a proxy to do that - surely it would make many sites unusable.  Do you know what browser they are using?  Govt. depts. may be stuck using an ancient browser or something which may not like your javascript json requests.

Comment: Yeah, seems odd, but can't find any other explanations.  They're using IE 8 on Vista: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)

Comment: I have since discovered this in the headers, which points to exactly what appliance is doing it:  Via : 1.1 NPS-PROXY.NPS.LOCAL:8004 (Cisco-IronPort-WSA/7.5.2-303) - but I'm still unable to stop the transform.